# How to change the color of text in Quotation mark in CMD (win 10)

Tags: powershell, cmd

The color of the text in Quotation mark in CMD is red by default and the background is black. It's very hard to see the text in Quotation mark. How can I change the color of the text?
[image: Example image]

Answer (score 0):

Try typing
color a or b or c

Letter a - f represent diff colors

Answer (score 0):

In the source code for the program remove all calls to `SetConsoleTextAttribute`. If that's not possible then **this is not a programming question**.